# Weird space after inline-block. Not between

Tags: whitespace, css, justify

I have this html code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And this css:

```
nav {
    display:block;    
}

nav ul {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height:100%;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 500px) / 4);
}

nav ul li:last-child { margin-right:0; }

nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n9uu4/)

As seen on jsfiddle there is white space after ul but nav is higher. Setting ul to 100% doesn't help and it doesn't seem to be margin. What is it?
The space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRBCe.png

Comment: Comment out the whitespace between the inline block elements, they are treated like words in a sentence, you get the space between them

Comment: And commenting out doesn't help :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi check here http://jsfiddle.net/j5LLR/1/ it works. The problem is because of using:

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your ul. So i ve added

```
vertical-align: top;
```

there too. Unfortunately inline-block causes many weird space issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `body` have `margin: 0`.

That will fix the problem!

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j5LLR/

Comment: Hello. I mean the space inside nav. :) http://i.imgur.com/NSKqsUV.png

Answer (score 1):

Change the `vertical-align` for `ul` for default is `baseline` making the calculation with `line-height` and other values create that gap:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

```
nav ul {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/n9uu4/2/**